# How to use decorator and property to check on class attributes' type and range efficiently?

Tags: python-3.x, decorator

```
import math
import random

# === Problem 1

class RectangularRoom(object):
"""
A RectangularRoom represents a rectangular region containing clean or dirty
tiles.

A room has a width and a height and contains (width * height) tiles. Each tile
has some fixed amount of dirt. The tile is considered clean only when the amount
of dirt on this tile is 0.
"""

    def __init__(self, width, height, dirt_amount):
        """
        Initializes a rectangular room with the specified width, height, and 
        dirt_amount on each tile.

        width: an integer > 0
        height: an integer > 0
        dirt_amount: an integer >= 0
        """

        self.width, self.height, self.dirt_amount = width, height, dirt_amount
        tiles = [(w,h) for w in range(width) for h in range(height)]
        self.room = {tile:dirt for tile in tiles for dirt in [dirt_amount]}
        #raise NotImplementedError

    def get_width(self):

        return self._width

    def set_width(self, value):
        if value <= 0 :
            raise ValueError("Must be greater than 0")
        self._width = value

     width = property(get_width,set_width)

    def __str__(self):
        return str((self.room))
```

This is what I've done so far with this room object. I am trying to make height, dirt_amount also limited to int and either greater than zero or greater and equal to zero. Is there an easier or more efficient way to code these constraints for the other two attributes?

Comment: Wait @crystalizeee, did this get formatted wrong, or have you not indented the functions that are below the class?

Comment: Omg my bad yeah when I was copy pasting this from IDE somehow it got formatted wrong. Can u ignore this silly mistake? Thx!

Answer (score 0):

```
import types
from functools import wraps


def range_check(func):
    code = func.__code__
    allargs = list(code.co_varnames[:code.co_argcount])
    @wraps
    def _decorator(*args, **kargs):
        positionals = allargs[:len(args)]
        for argname, check in func.__annotations__.items():
            if argname in kargs:
                if not check(kargs[argname]):
                    raise TypeError('"%s" check failed' % argname)
            elif argname in positionals:
                pos = positionals.index(argname)
                if not check(args[pos]):
                    raise TypeError('"%s" check failed' % argname)
            else:
                # argument defaulted
                pass
        return func(*args, **kargs)
    return _decorator

def range(ratio):
    return 0 <= ratio and ratio <= 0.5

class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, age, pay):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.pay = pay
    @range_check
    def giveRaise(self, ratio: range):
        self.pay *= (1 + ratio)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    alice = Employee('alice', 20, 50000)
    alice.giveRaise(0.1)
    alice.giveRaise(0.6)
```

This is a sample code to do checking of arguments passed to function.
1. use `__annotations__` in python3 to pass check functions in function declaration.
2. use 'co_varnames[co_argcount]' to retrieve argument name list.
3. positional arguments are always placed before keyword arguments.